# How does this circuit behave? (cap charge/discharge)

Tags: circuit-analysis, capacitor, circuit-design, pulse, charge

[image]

When I pulse, start signal should be at least 50ms HIGH before falling. To do this I must design R and C values to estimate capacitor C1 charge/discharge times. I get the schmidt trigger part, but I'm a bit lost when it comes to how the capacitor C1 is charging/discharging.

Can someone help me explaining how does this part of the circuit works?? (before buffer)

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Welcome! Have you tried to simulate it?

Comment: You might be confused, how to handle the opamp.   You can consider the connection to the opamp to be an 'open circuit' here.  i.e. pretend it's not even there.   Then you only have to consider the 2 resistors and capacitor.   The 2 answers given thus far don't mention that, so I thought I'd just add it.

Answer (score 1):

When the pulse button is pressed, C1 will discharge. (via the loop trough +VCC, the switch, R1, back to the capacitor). The buffer's positive input will rise as C1 discharges. When the button is released, the buffer's positive input will remain high trough the now-discharged C1. As C1 begins to charge trough R1 and R2 the buffer's positive input voltage will fall toward zero.

Thus, for discharging only R1 matters, charging is done trough both R1 and R2 in series.

Note that this circuit will also provide a pulse at power-up when C1 is discharged.

Answer (score 0):

When the button is pressed, C1 is charged up to Vcc via R1. When it is released, it is discharged via R1+R2. To make the circuit work properly, R2 must be much larger than R1 (i.e. 100x larger); R1 could be on the order of 100 Ohms which means that R2 should be about 10k Ohms or larger. With these values, you can assume that C1 charges to Vcc instantly as soon as you press the button. When you release it, the voltage Vc decays exponentially with a time constant of tau=(R1+R2)C1.

The circuit also pulses once when it's powered up due to C1 being tied to Vcc. (If you tie it to ground instead, it won't do that.)

Comment: Actually, pushing the button discharges the cap trough R1, releasing the button charges it...

Comment: This is really just a question of how you define your reference potentials and doesn't change the result of the analysis. I called it "charge" because Vc becomes more positive during that phase. (Taking either Vcc or ground as the reference.)

Comment: Most people would consider "charging" of a capacitor to be the action of adding electrical energy to it.   You're right the math works either way.    Saying it "charges" as the voltage across it decreases is gonna confuse the OP though.   Just my 2 cents...